# Neo4j : Advices for hardware sizing and config

Tags: neo4j

I've been playing with a neo4j 2.0 db for a few months and I plan to install the db on a dedicated server. I've already tried several configs of neo4j (jvm, caches, ...) but I'm still not sure to have found the best one.
Therefore, it seems better to ask to the experts :)

### Context

**Db primitives:**

Nodes = 224,114,478

Relationships = 417,681,104

Properties = 224,342,951

**Db files:**

- nodestore.db = 3.064Gb
- relationshipstore.db = 13.460Gb
- propertystore.db = 8.982 Gb
- propertystore.db.string = 5.998 Gb
- propertystore.db.arrays = 1kb

**OS server:**

Windows server 2012 (64b)

**Db usage:**

Mostly graph traversals using cypher queries.

Perfs are not too bad on my dev laptop even if some queries have huge lags (I suspect that the main reason is swap caused by lack of RAM)

**Graph specificities:**

I suspect that some nodes may be huge hubs (till 1M relationships) but it should remain exceptional.

---

What would be your advices regarding:

- hardware sizing,
- neo4j configuration:

  - heap size,
  - use memory map buffer (is there any reason to keep the value to false with windows ?)
  - cache type,
  - recommended jvm settings for windows,
  - ...

Thanks in advance !

laurent

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Try to clarify your question. Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Comment: This question seems like a better fit for [sf].

Comment: I didn't know Server Fault site but you"re right that this question is borderline and may be better suited on S.F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The on-disk size of your graph is in total ~32 GB. Neo4j has a two layered cache architecture. The first layer is the file buffer cache. Ideally it should have the same size as the on disk graph, so ~32GB in your case.

*IMPORTANT* When running Neo4j on Windows, the file buffer cache is part of Java heap (due to the suckiness of Windows by itself). On Linux/Mac it's off heap. That is reason why I generally do not recommend production environments for Neo4j on Windows.

`cache_type` should be `hpc` when using enterprise edition and `soft` for community.

To have some reasonable amount for the second cache layer (object cache) I'd suggest to have a machine with at least 64GB RAM. Since file buffer and object cache are both on heap, make heap large and consider using G1: `-Xmx60G -XX:+UseG1GC`. Observe GC behaviour by uncommenting gc logging in `neo4j-wrapper.conf` and tweak the settings step by step.

Please note that Neo4j 2.2 might come with a different file buffer cache implementation that works off heap on Windows as well.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I'll test G1 for garbage collection and will have a look to v2.2

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at these two guides for performance tuning and hardware sizing calculations:

- http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-performance-tuning/
- http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-sizing-and-hardware-calculator/

Comment: I've read the performance tuning guide (several times) but was still not sure about potential specificities in windows environment. But you're right, they're very good resources on the subject.