# Which hardware to choose in Neo4j

Tags: optimization, neo4j, cypher, hardware, sizing

I'm beginner in neo4j and I would like to store more than 500 millions nodes and more than 20 billions relationships.
Which hardware is the best to deal with all this data ?
Thanks a lot.

Maxime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j does not restrict users to use certain hardware specifications. However it recommends minimum specifications for RAM, CPU and disk. That are as follows:

**RAM:**

- Must have at least 2 GB
- Good to have around 16 GB

**CPU:**

- Must have an Intel Core I3 processor
- Good to have an Intel Core I7 processor

**Disk:**

- Must have SATA drives with 15k RPM
- Good to have SSDs

Also have a look on these as well [Neo4j : Advices for hardware sizing and config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26811902/10736243) and https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-sizing-and-hardware-calculator/

Answer (score 1):

Just for general recommendations, the top two things to look for are plenty of memory and fast SSDs (especially for larger graphs).

Neo4j has a pagecache for caching node and relationship graph topography, and the more of this you can fit into the pagecache the better. We typically recommend between 8 to 31 GB heap in addition to the pagecache depending on the volume and kind of queries you expect to run.

SSDs aid in Neo4j's index-free adjacency structure, as this involves pointer chasing across the disk. This is mostly for when you can't fit all of the graph in pagecache, but this also aids in lookup of node and relationship properties.